# How to handle APNS Message by clicking "View" button when the app is not in active?

Tags: iphone, ios, apple-push-notifications

Am new to use APNS in iPhone app. I have used and received the message in all scenarios. When the `user clicks the "View" button from the APNS alert i should do the actions in the app and navigate the user to 3rd tab`.

But when the app is in **In Active (The app not in use)** `i can't trigger the actions in the app`. I have used the below code in "didFinishLaunch" but not used.

```
    NSString *params=[[launchOptions objectForKey:@"UIApplicationLaunchOptionsRemoteNotificationKey"] objectForKey:@"aps"];
    NSDictionary *remoteNotif = [launchOptions objectForKey: UIApplicationLaunchOptionsRemoteNotificationKey];
    NSLog(@"remoteNotif : %@", remoteNotif);
    if ([params length] > 0 ) 
    {
        UIAlertView *messageReceivedAlert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"My APP" message:@"New Message Recevied From APNS in IN-Active Stage" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:@"OK", nil];
        [messageReceivedAlert show];
        [messageReceivedAlert release];
    }
```

It always returns (null).

Can anyone please help me to do this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this :

`- (void) application:(UIApplication*)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary*)userInfo`

And you can check for inactive by using

```
if([UIApplication sharedApplication].applicationState == UIApplicationStateInactive)
```